# Accessing nested keys in object and compare them to other object keys, but the 2nd one is an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

So I got this issue trying to compare and access data in nested objects and compare tham to an array with objects (this is not nested).

To simulate it looks something like this:

```
const members = [
      {
        name: 'Angelica',
        age: '25',
        sex: 'female',
        phone: '123456789',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dominic',
        age: '30',
        sex: 'male',
        phone: '987654321',
      },
    ];

    const updates = {
      123456789: {
        date: '12.02-2019',
        warnings: {},
        errors: {}
      },
      987654321: {
        date: '20.01-2020',
        warnings: {
          somethinghere: {
            warning1: 'warning',
            allok: 'yes',
          }
        },
        errors: {},
      }
    }
```

So first I need to check if phone in members is equal to the key in object, then I need to find out if there is any warnings (warnings not empty). I've tried to loop through members with forEach as `members.forEach((member) => {
if (Object.keys(updates) === member.name) }`
But it does not seem to work. The info like warning in updates is not declared initially, but will appear in the state after certain changes.

Comment: You want to check phone only or all members attributes?

Comment: @ZivBen-Or Phone only before I do something further.

Comment: O.K,  so see my answer below  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const members = [
    {
      name: 'Angelica',
      age: '25',
      sex: 'female',
      phone: '123456789',
    },
    {
      name: 'Dominic',
      age: '30',
      sex: 'male',
      phone: '987654321',
    },
  ];

  const updates = {
    123456789: {
      date: '12.02-2019',
      warnings: {},
      errors: {}
    },
    987654321: {
      date: '20.01-2020',
      warnings: {
        somethinghere: {
          warning1: 'warning',
          allok: 'yes',
        }
      },
      errors: {},
    }
  }

  members.forEach(member => {
      Object.entries(updates).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          if(key === member.phone && JSON.stringify(value.warnings) === '{}'){
                console.log(key)
          }
      })
  })
```

(`JSON.stringify(obj) === '{}'` Checks if the object is empty)

Comment: Is it possible to also check if value.warnings object as same amount of keys as errors? So if there is 2 keys in warnings its true if also errors has 2 keys

Comment: Try this: `if(Object.keys(value.warnings).length == Object.keys(value.errors).length)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map` and `Object.keys` methods.

```js
const members = [ { name: 'Angelica', age: '25', sex: 'female', phone: '123456789', }, { name: 'Dominic', age: '30', sex: 'male', phone: '987654321', }, ];
const updates = { 123456789: { date: '12.02-2019', warnings: {}, errors: {} }, 987654321: { date: '20.01-2020', warnings: { somethinghere: { warning1: 'warning', allok: 'yes', } }, errors: {}, } }


var result = members.map(({phone}) => ({phone, hasWarnings: Object.keys(updates[phone].warnings).length > 0}) );
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys(updates)` is an array so you should use `includes`:

```
if (Object.keys(updates).includes(member.phone) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do `const update = updates[member.phone];` to see if an update is available, this will be undefined if no such phone exists in updates key set.

Then `const warnings = Object.keys(update.warnings);` will give you list of warning keys.

```js
const members = [{
  name: 'Angelica',
  age: '25',
  sex: 'female',
  phone: '123456789',
}, {
  name: 'Dominic',
  age: '30',
  sex: 'male',
  phone: '987654321',
}, ];
const updates = {
  123456789: {
    date: '12.02-2019',
    warnings: {},
    errors: {}
  },
  987654321: {
    date: '20.01-2020',
    warnings: {
      somethinghere: {
        warning1: 'warning',
        allok: 'yes',
      }
    },
    errors: {},
  }
}

members.forEach((member) => {
  const update = updates[member.phone];
  if (update) {
    const warnings = Object.keys(update.warnings);
    console.log(warnings);
    if (warnings.length === 0) {
      console.log(`no warnings for member ${member.name}'s update`);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`no updates for member ${member.name}`);
  }
});
```